# CSS - IE webpage looks stupid compared to FF and Chrome, and can't figure out why

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

So, here is my problem. I've gotten the task to make this css file compatible into IE. At the moment it is being run on FF, where the problem is, that sometimes it runs out of memory because of the ajax. So the company want's it transformed to IE. Our problem is, as you can see by the screenshots, that they do not look similar in ANY way. And me and my mate really can't figure out for the life of us what the problem is.

The black things on the screens are just obscoured because it's private :)

How it is supposed to look:
http://prntscr.com/49g7j3

How it looks on IE:
http://prntscr.com/49g7um

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head><style type="text/css" id="customCSS"><!--
        html, body {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #8FAE9F;
            font-family: Trebuchet MS;
            font-size: 27px;
            font-weight: bold;
            height: 99%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .column.OBJ0, .column.OBJ1 {
            min-width: 11.7em;
            padding-left: 4.5em;
            padding-right: 4.3em;
        }
        .blueBorder, .thresholds {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 5px;
            width: auto;
        }
        .thresholds {
            display: inline;
            float: left;
        }
        .Threshold_NONE {
            color: black;
        }
        .Threshold_INFO {
            color: green;
        }
        .Threshold_WARNING {
            color: yellow;
        }
        .Threshold_ALERT {
            color: red;
        }
        .Threshold_INFO, .Threshold_WARNING, .Threshold_ALERT, .Threshold_NONE {
            font-size: 5em;
        }
        .displayText {
        }
        .column {
            display: inline;
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: text-top;
        }
        .header {
            color: black;
            font-size: 3em;
            margin-left: -4px;
            margin-right: -4px;
            margin-top: -4px;
        }
        .column {
            display: inline-block;
            line-height: normal;
            white-space: normal;
        }
        .columnwrapper {
            min-width: 378px;
            text-align: center;
            white-space: nowrap;
            width: 5%;
        }
        .displayAgent {
        }
        .displayAgent img {
            float: left;
            margin-bottom: auto;
            margin-right: 0.5em;
            margin-top: auto;
        }
        .displayAgent1 {
        }
        .displayAgent2 {
            background-color: #E6E6E6;
        }
        .displayAgentName {
            display: table;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .displayAgentStatusImg {
            padding-left: 5px;
        }
        .displayAgentStatus {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 71px;
        }
        .displayAgentStateTime {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 61px;
        }
        .displayAgentStatus_LoggedIn {
        }
        .displayAgentStatus_NotReady {
        }
        .displayAgentStatus_Ready {
        }
        .displayAgentStatus_Reserved {
        }
        .displayAgentStatus_LoggedOut {
        }
        .displayAgentStatus_Talking {
        }
        .displayAgentStatus_Working {
        }
        div .displayAgentStateTime {
            display: none;
        }
        div .displayAgentStatus {
            display: none;
        }
        .PoweredBy {
            bottom: 10px;
            display: none;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            padding: 5px;
            position: fixed;
            right: 10px;
        }
        .lastupdate {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
            display: table;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            margin-top: 0;
            position: inherit;
            width: 7em;
        }
        .viewerDisplayItemErrorPanel {
            color: red;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .column {
            float: left;
        }
        .headline.remedyItem {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .remedyItem span {
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 1em;
            max-height: 1.2em;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        div.headline.remedyItem {
            border-bottom: 4px solid;
            text-align: center;
        }
        span.remedyId {
            width: 6em;
        }
        span.remedyCustomer {
            width: 6em;
        }
        span.remedyPriority {
            width: 2em;
        }
        span.remedyCaseTitle {
            text-align: left;
            width: 17em;
        }
        span.remedySLA {
            width: 5em;
        }
        span.remedySubSlaType {
            display: none;
        }
        span.remedyHidden {
        }
        span.remedyShowSLA {
            width: 5em;
        }
        span.remedyGroup {
            width: 6em;
        }
        div.column.Remedy {
            clear: left;
            margin-top: 0.5em;
        }
        div.column.Remedy h2 {
            display: none;
        }
        div.uccx_exchange_user span.exchangeStatus {
            display: none;
        }
        div.uccx_exchange_user span.uccxStatus {
            display: none;
        }
        div.uccx_exchange_user span.user {
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 1em;
            width: 3.8em;
        }
        div.uccx_exchange_user img {
            margin-top: 0.2em;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .viewerDisplayItemShowPanel.øst {
            clear: right;
            float: right;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .viewerDisplayItemShowPanel.vest {
            clear: left;
            float: left;
            text-align: right;
        }
        .viewerDisplayItemShowPanel.øst div img {
            float: left;
            margin-left: 0.1em;
            margin-right: 0.5em;
        }
        .viewerDisplayItemShowPanel.vest div img {
            float: right;
            margin-left: 0.5em;
            margin-right: 0.1em;
        }
        .column h2.header {
            font-size: 1.3em;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .headline.remedyItem .remedyPriority {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
            display: none;
        }
        .headline.remedyItem .remedyCustomer {
            margin-right: 3em;
        }
        span.NOT_SET {
            color: white;
        }
        div.FIX_AT_NONE .remedyId {
            color: yellow;
        }
        span.NORMAL_ALERT, span.FIX_AT_ALERT {
            color: red;
        }
        span.NORMAL_WARNING, span.FIX_AT_WARNING {
            color: yellow;
        }
        span.NONE_WARNING, span.NONE_NONE {
            color: blue;
        }
        span.NONE_ALERT {
            color: purple;
        }
        .BURNED {
            color: red;
        }
        .P1.remedyPriority {
            background-color: red;
        }
        .P2.remedyPriority {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        span.RESPECTED {
            color: green;
        }
        .column.OBJ2 .OBJ1 {
            margin-top: 1em;
        }
        span.remedyUserLoginID {
            display: none;
        }
        span.penaltyOn {
            display: none;
        }--></style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.resource.JQueryResourceReference/jquery/jquery.min-ver-CFA9051CC0B05EB519F1E16B2A6645D7.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior/res/js/wicket-event-jquery.min-ver-59CE6C5F72E4E37919EA3791EFB48699.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../wicket/resource/org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior/res/js/wicket-ajax-jquery.min-ver-4423B6C292632D275DB02E79B0F75A69.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" id="wicket-ajax-base-url">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        Wicket.Ajax.baseUrl = "viewer/KoordinationNSI?8";
        /*]]>*/
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" id="AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior-timers">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        if (typeof (Wicket.TimerHandles) === 'undefined') {
            Wicket.TimerHandles = {}
        }
        /*]]>*/
    </script>

    <title>NetDesign Wallboard Display</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../images/ND-net-RGB-Web.ico"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        Wicket.Event.add(window, "load", function(event) {
            Wicket.TimerHandles['id1e'] = setTimeout('Wicket.Ajax.ajax({\"u\":\"./KoordinationNSI?8-2.IBehaviorListener.0-wallboardShow\",\"c\":\"id1e\"});', 1000);
            ;
        });
        /*]]>*/
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wallboardShow" id="id1e">

        <div class="column OBJ0 UC">
            <h2 class="header">UC</h2>

            <div class="viewerDisplayItemShowPanel vest OBJ0 HTHA">
                <div class="uccx_exchange_user">
                    <span class="user">HTHA</span>
                    <span class="exchangeStatus">GREEN</span>
                    <span class="uccxStatus">READY</span>
                    <img class="displayAgentStatusImg" src="../wicket/resource/com.netdesign.exchange.panel.DisplayItemExchangeShowPanel/GREEN-ver-5C507ED333BB13CEA555F8FCCECCA98F.png" alt="GREEN"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="viewerDisplayItemShowPanel øst OBJ1 LLH">
                <div class="uccx_exchange_user">
                    <span class="user">LLH</span>
                    <span class="exchangeStatus">GREEN</span>
                    <span class="uccxStatus">READY</span>
                    <img class="displayAgentStatusImg" src="../wicket/resource/com.netdesign.exchange.panel.DisplayItemExchangeShowPanel/GREEN-ver-5C507ED333BB13CEA555F8FCCECCA98F.png" alt="GREEN"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="viewerDisplayItemShowPanel vest OBJ2 PBIH">
                <div class="uccx_exchange_user">
                    <span class="user">PBIH</span>
                    <span class="exchangeStatus">GREEN</span>
                    <span class="uccxStatus">READY</span>
                    <img class="displayAgentStatusImg" src="../wicket/resource/com.netdesign.exchange.panel.DisplayItemExchangeShowPanel/GREEN-ver-5C507ED333BB13CEA555F8FCCECCA98F.png" alt="GREEN"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="viewerDisplayItemShowPanel øst OBJ3 BSC">
                <div class="uccx_exchange_user">
                    <span class="user">BSC</span>
                    <span class="exchangeStatus">BLUE_FREE</span>
                    <span class="uccxStatus">LOG_OUT</span>
                    <img class="displayAgentStatusImg" src="../wicket/resource/com.netdesign.exchange.panel.DisplayItemExchangeShowPanel/BLUE_FREE-ver-71B1BA561B8371A0E2FB26CD213BF63E.png" alt="BLUE_FREE"/>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="column OBJ1 NSI">
            <h2 class="header">NSI</h2>

            <div class="viewerDisplayItemShowPanel vest OBJ0 KENJO">
                <div class="uccx_exchange_user">
                    <span class="user">KENJO</span>
                    <span class="exchangeStatus">BLUE</span>
                    <span class="uccxStatus">LOG_OUT</span>
                    <img class="displayAgentStatusImg" src="../wicket/resource/com.netdesign.exchange.panel.DisplayItemExchangeShowPanel/BLUE-ver-6BD832A3D267DC6EAB17FFBCF05C20B8.png" alt="BLUE"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="viewerDisplayItemShowPanel øst OBJ1 PNI">
                <div class="uccx_exchange_user">
                    <span class="user">PNI</span>
                    <span class="exchangeStatus">GREEN</span>
                    <span class="uccxStatus">READY</span>
                    <img class="displayAgentStatusImg" src="../wicket/resource/com.netdesign.exchange.panel.DisplayItemExchangeShowPanel/GREEN-ver-5C507ED333BB13CEA555F8FCCECCA98F.png" alt="GREEN"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="viewerDisplayItemShowPanel øst OBJ2 JABOLA">
                <div class="uccx_exchange_user">
                    <span class="user">JABOLA</span>
                    <span class="exchangeStatus">GREEN</span>
                    <span class="uccxStatus">READY</span>
                    <img class="displayAgentStatusImg" src="../wicket/resource/com.netdesign.exchange.panel.DisplayItemExchangeShowPanel/GREEN-ver-5C507ED333BB13CEA555F8FCCECCA98F.png" alt="GREEN"/>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="column OBJ2 Remedy">
            <h2 class="header">Remedy</h2>

            <div class="viewerDisplayItemShowPanel OBJ0 _st">
                <div class="headline remedyItem">
                    <span class="remedyId">Sagsnr</span>
                    <span class="remedyUserLoginID">Tekniker</span>
                    <span class="remedyCustomer">Kunde</span>
                    <span class="remedyPriority">Priotet</span>
                    <span class="remedyCaseTitle">Sagstitel</span>
                    <span class="remedySLA remedyHidden">SLA_ORG</span>
                    <span class="remedySubSlaType remedyHidden">SLA_Sub_Type</span>
                    <span class="remedyShowSLA">SLA</span>
                    <span class="remedyGroup">Gruppe</span>
                    <span class="penaltyOn">Bod</span>
                </div>
                <div class="remedyItem NONE_ALERT">
                    <span class="remedyId">ND370090</span>
                    <span class="remedyUserLoginID">N/A</span>
                    <span class="remedyCustomer">PANDACONNECT A/S</span>
                    <span class="remedyPriority P4">P4</span>
                    <span class="remedyCaseTitle">Anyconnect VPN Pandaconnect åbning af porte til global connect.</span>
                    <span class="remedySLA remedyHidden">Ingen SLA</span>
                    <span class="remedySubSlaType remedyHidden">NONE_ALERT</span>
                    <span class="remedyShowSLA NONE_ALERT">-47:31:25</span>
                    <span class="remedyGroup">RANDOM TEXT</span>
                    <span class="penaltyOn">Nej</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="viewerDisplayItemShowPanel OBJ1 Vest">
                <div class="headline remedyItem">
                    <span class="remedyId">Sagsnr</span>
                    <span class="remedyUserLoginID">Tekniker</span>
                    <span class="remedyCustomer">Kunde</span>
                    <span class="remedyPriority">Priotet</span>
                    <span class="remedyCaseTitle">Sagstitel</span>
                    <span class="remedySLA remedyHidden">SLA_ORG</span>
                    <span class="remedySubSlaType remedyHidden">SLA_Sub_Type</span>
                    <span class="remedyShowSLA">SLA</span>
                    <span class="remedyGroup">Gruppe</span>
                    <span class="penaltyOn">Bod</span>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="viewerDisplayItemShowPanel OBJ2">
                <div class="headline remedyItem">
                    <span class="remedyId">Sagsnr</span>
                    <span class="remedyUserLoginID">Tekniker</span>
                    <span class="remedyCustomer">Kunde</span>
                    <span class="remedyPriority">Priotet</span>
                    <span class="remedyCaseTitle">Sagstitel</span>
                    <span class="remedySLA remedyHidden">SLA_ORG</span>
                    <span class="remedySubSlaType remedyHidden">SLA_Sub_Type</span>
                    <span class="remedyShowSLA">SLA</span>
                    <span class="remedyGroup">Gruppe</span>
                    <span class="penaltyOn">Bod</span>
                </div>
                <div class="remedyItem NONE_NONE">
                    <span class="remedyId">ND355264</span>
                    <span class="remedyUserLoginID">N/A</span>
                    <span class="remedyCustomer">RANDOM TEXT</span>
                    <span class="remedyPriority P4">P4</span>
                    <span class="remedyCaseTitle">WAAS konfiguration</span>
                    <span class="remedySLA remedyHidden">Ingen SLA</span>
                    <span class="remedySubSlaType remedyHidden">NONE_NONE</span>
                    <span class="remedyShowSLA NONE_NONE">-2134:27:26</span>
                    <span class="remedyGroup">NSI</span>
                    <span class="penaltyOn">Nej</span>
                </div><div class="remedyItem NONE_NONE">
                    <span class="remedyId">ND370497</span>
                    <span class="remedyUserLoginID">N/A</span>
                    <span class="remedyCustomer">RANDOM TEXT</span>
                    <span class="remedyPriority P4">P4</span>
                    <span class="remedyCaseTitle">RANDOM TEXT</span>
                    <span class="remedySLA remedyHidden">Ingen SLA</span>
                    <span class="remedySubSlaType remedyHidden">NONE_NONE</span>
                    <span class="remedyShowSLA NONE_NONE">47:23:17</span>
                    <span class="remedyGroup">NSI</span>
                    <span class="penaltyOn">Nej</span>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="lastupdate">2014-8-4 13:43:13</div>         

        <div class="PoweredBy">RANDOM TEXT</div>
    </div> 
</body>
```

PS. We are interns, so this is a rather small problem for some of you I guess, but we can't figure it out! :)

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing on?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you remove the `<!--`..`-->` comment markers around the CSS?

Comment: Also, is `øst` a valid class name? It doesn't start with an ASCII letter. And you have a line `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>` somewhere halfway down the document, and there was a rule somewhere that such meta commands should be near the top of the document, within the first 512 bytes.

Comment: Just tried changing it, and that doesn't seem to be where the problem is.